# How can I detect if Raspberry Pi is plugged in a windows PC

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I have a security problem with a Raspberry Pi device I'll like to know if this device is plugged in via Ethernet, with Windows.

I tried to use Pcap in JAVA but I don't know how could I do it, if someone could help me, only knowing the way to detected, and I will find the way to make the JAVA code.

Thanks for all

Comment: Do you mean plugged in via USB? Or something else?

Comment: is plugged in via Ethernet, USB is only for energy in this case.

Comment: I'd look into doing a network discovery and checking if any MAC addresses returned match the Pi's Vendor Id (See this http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt for OUI references). It shows raspberry pi as: B827EB.